# General expression for time evolution operator in terms of path integral

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, path-integral, time-evolution

Given that I know that the time evolution operator $U^{i\rightarrow f}$ for initial and final states $|\psi^{i,f}\rangle$, defined by
$$|\psi^f\rangle:=U^{i\rightarrow f}|\psi^i\rangle.$$
How do I show the general form of $U^{i\rightarrow f}$ in terms of a path integral?

I assume that given the action of the system $S$, it should I think roughly take on the form
$$
U^{i\rightarrow f}=\int_i^f \mathcal{D}x' |\psi^f\rangle e^{iS[x']/\hbar} \langle\psi^i|
$$
but how do I show this explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection between the time-evolution operator $\hat{U}(t_f,t_i)$ and the path integral is
$$\begin{align} {}_H\langle q_f,t_f|q_i,t_i\rangle_H~=~&{}_H\langle q_f,0|\hat{U}(t_f,t_i)|q_i,0\rangle_H \cr
~=~&\int_{q(t_i)=q_i}^{q(t_f)=q_f}\! {\cal D}q~{\cal D}p~\exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\!dt \left( p\dot{q}-H(q,p,t) \right)\right\}\cr
~\stackrel{p\text{-int.}}{\sim}~&\int_{q(t_i)=q_i}^{q(t_f)=q_f}\! {\cal D}q~\exp\left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{t_i}^{t_f}\!dt~ L(q,\dot{q},t) \right\}.\end{align}$$